# PHPUnit Test, recieve warning when referencing a class that has a member variable

Tags: php, phpunit

I receive the following error when running a PHPUnit Test:

1) Warning
The data provider specified for CarTest::countWheels is invalid.
syntax error, unexpected 'float' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

**Why can't I have a Wheel class with member variables and make a reference to Wheel::NUMBER_OF_WHEELS in the CarTest class?**

**Is this because in a Unit Test, you are supposed to only be testing the functionality within the class itself?  In my case, just test items within class Car only and do not make references to an external class, such as Wheel?**

However, if I were to comment out the member variable in class Wheel:

```
// private float tirePressure = null;
```

*I get no error.*  Note, I did not comment out the member function.  So, member functions do not cause issues...but, member variables...it does not like?

Or, if I were to delete the Wheel class and instead do the following:

1) In class Car, define

```
const NUMBER_OF_WHEELS = 4;
```

2) In class CarTest

Change From:

```
'Good Data: (alpha)' => [2, Wheel::NUMBER_OF_WHEELS, 8]
```

Change To:

```
'Good Data: (alpha)' => [2, Car::NUMBER_OF_WHEELS, 8]
```

*I get no error.  AND, I have defined member variables in the Car class.*

**My code that generates the error**

```
// =============== Car.php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);    // strict typing

namespace App;


class Car
{
    private $make;
    private $model;
    private $color;

    function __construct(string $make)
    {
        $this->make = $make;
        echo "OK\n";
    }


    public function getMake() : string
    {
        return $this->make;
    }


    public function countWheels(int $numCars, int $numWheels) : int
    {
        return $numCars * $numWheels;
    }
}

// =============== Wheel.php
<?php

namespace App;


class Wheel
{
    /**
     *  @var    int     Typical number of wheels for a car.
     */
    const NUMBER_OF_WHEELS = 4;


    private float tirePressure = null;

    public function sayHelloWorld()
    {
        echo "Hello World!\n";
    }
}

// =============== CarTest.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);    // strict typing


use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Car;
use App\Wheel;

class CarTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     *  ========================================================================
     *  @test
     *  ========================================================================
     */
    public function true_asserts_to_true()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }


    /**
     *  ========================================================================
     *  Test: Get make of Car
     *
     *  @dataProvider getMakeProvider
     *  @test
     *  ========================================================================
     */
    public function getMake($expected)
    {
        $myCar = new Car("Ford");
        $actual = $myCar->getMake();
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }


    /**
     *  ========================================================================
     *  Data Provider for: getMake
     *  ========================================================================
     */
    public function getMakeProvider()
    {
        // NOTE: This is an associative array.  Therefore, each index must be unique (hence, 'alpha', 'beta', etc.).
        return [
            // NOTE: To generate a failure, set the expected value to something other than the actual value.
            'Good Data: (alpha)' => ["Ford"]
        ];
    }


    /**
     *  ========================================================================
     *  Test: Get make of Car
     *
     *  @dataProvider countWheelsProvider
     *  @test
     *  ========================================================================
     */
    public function countWheels($numCars, $numWheels, $expected)
    {
        // echo "PHPUnit: " . PHPUnit_Runner_Version.id() ."\n";
        $myCar = new Car("Ford");
        $actual = $myCar->countWheels($numCars, $numWheels);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }


    /**
     *  ========================================================================
     *  Data Provider for: countWheels
     *  ========================================================================
     */
    public function countWheelsProvider()
    {
        // NOTE: This is an associative array.  Therefore, each index must be unique (hence, 'alpha', 'beta', etc.).
        return [
            // NOTE: To generate a failure, set the expected value to something other than the actual value.
            'Good Data: (alpha)' => [2, Wheel::NUMBER_OF_WHEELS, 8]
        ];
    }
}
```

**My System:**

PHPUnit  6.3.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Runtime: PHP 7.0.24-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 with Xdebug 2.5.5

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you cannot give class variables a type...

```
private float tirePressure = null;
```

Needs to be

```
private $tirePressure = null;
```

Also you need to gave the `$` to denote a variable.

Comment: Thanks Nigel.  Being new to Unit Testing, I was looking deeper than the incorrect syntax and the desire to specify type.  UGH!